# UWP App Crash Using Extended Execution

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps

I have implemented the example given by Magnus Montin [Non-suspending UWP Desktop Apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2018/01/30/non-suspending-uwp-desktop-apps/)

We are an ISV and don't have access to users machines so have had to implement the solution in accordance the directions Magnus gives for apps that are submitted to the store

> replace the ExtendedExecutionForegroundSession with an
>   ExtendedExecutionSession, set its Reason property to
>   ExtendedExecutionReason.Unspecified

We also use Template10. My implementation iin App.xaml.cs is

```
ExtendedExecutionSession _session;
private void SessionRevoked(object sender, ExtendedExecutionRevokedEventArgs args)
{
    if (_session != null)
    {
        _session.Dispose();
        _session = null;
    }
}
private async Task PreventFromSuspending()
// stolen from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2018/01/30/non-suspending-uwp-desktop-apps/
{
    ExtendedExecutionSession newSession = new ExtendedExecutionSession();
    newSession.Reason = ExtendedExecutionReason.Unspecified;
    newSession.Revoked += SessionRevoked;

    ExtendedExecutionResult result = await newSession.RequestExtensionAsync();
    switch (result)
    {
        case ExtendedExecutionResult.Allowed:
            _session = newSession;
            break;
        default:
        case ExtendedExecutionResult.Denied:
            newSession.Dispose();
            break;
    }
}
public override async Task OnInitializeAsync(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    if (_session == null)
        await PreventFromSuspending();
}
```

This is now in the store and is implicated in our most frequent crash in the AppCenter. The project is called UWP. The stack trace is

```
    myapp::app::_preventfromsuspending_d__4 movenext()
stowed_exception_system.exception 8007139F: stowed_exception_system.exception

System.Private.Interop
System::Runtime::InteropServices::McgMarshal ActivateInstance() McgMarshal.cs:1331
UWP.McgInterop.dll
Windows::ApplicationModel::ExtendedExecution::ExtendedExecutionSession. ctor() SafeTypes.g.cs:50719
UWP.exe
MyApp::App::_PreventFromSuspending_d__4 MoveNext() App.xaml.cs:80
SharedLibrary.dll
System::Runtime::ExceptionServices::ExceptionDispatchInfo Throw() ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61
System.Private.Threading
System::Runtime::CompilerServices::TaskAwaiter ThrowForNonSuccess() TaskAwaiter.cs:182
System.Private.Threading
System::Runtime::CompilerServices::TaskAwaiter HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification() TaskAwaiter.cs:151
System.Private.Threading
System::Runtime::CompilerServices::TaskAwaiter ValidateEnd() TaskAwaiter.cs:123
System.Private.Threading
System::Runtime::CompilerServices::ConfiguredTaskAwaitable::ConfiguredTaskAwaiter GetResult() TaskAwaiter.cs:108
UWP.exe
MyApp::App::_OnInitializeAsync_d__5 MoveNext() App.xaml.cs:16707566
SharedLibrary.dll
System::Runtime::ExceptionServices::ExceptionDispatchInfo Throw() ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61
System.Private.Threading
System::Runtime::CompilerServices::TaskAwaiter ThrowForNonSuccess() TaskAwaiter.cs:182
System.Private.Threading
System::Runtime::CompilerServices::TaskAwaiter HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification() TaskAwaiter.cs:151
System.Private.Threading
System::Runtime::CompilerServices::TaskAwaiter ValidateEnd() TaskAwaiter.cs:123
System.Private.Threading
System::Runtime::CompilerServices::ConfiguredTaskAwaitable::ConfiguredTaskAwaiter GetResult() TaskAwaiter.cs:108
Template10Library.dll
Template10::Common::BootStrapper::_StartupOrchestratorAsync_d__112 MoveNext() +0x00000000000002A0
SharedLibrary.dll
System::Runtime::ExceptionServices::ExceptionDispatchInfo Throw() ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61
System.Private.Threading
System::Runtime::CompilerServices::AsyncMethodBuilderCore::__c _ThrowAsync_b__9_0() AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:971
System.Private.Threading
System::Threading::SendOrPostCallback Invoke() +0x0000000000000028
System.Private.Threading
System::Threading::WinRTSynchronizationContext::Invoker InvokeCore() SynchronizationContext.cs:170
System.Private.Interop
System::Runtime::InteropServices::McgMarshal ThrowOnExternalCallFailed() McgMarshal.cs:1267
UWP.McgInterop.dll
__Interop::ComCallHelpers Call() SharedStubs.g.cs:11991
UWP.McgInterop.dll
__Interop::ForwardComStubs.Stub_16_System __Canon_() SharedStubs.g.cs:645
Microsoft.AppCenter.dll
Microsoft::AppCenter::Utils::ApplicationLifecycleHelper._ ctor_b__17_1$catch$0() +0x000000000000001D
System.ObjectModel.dll
System::Collections::Specialized::NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler Invoke() +0x000000000000001B
UWP.McgInterop.dll
__Interop::Intrinsics.HasThisCall__45_System __Canon_() +0x0000000000000036
UWP.McgInterop.dll
__Interop::ReverseComStubs.Stub_9_System __Canon_() SharedStubs.g.cs:27913
System.Private.Interop
System::Runtime::InteropServices::McgMarshal ThrowOnExternalCallFailed() McgMarshal.cs:1267
UWP.McgInterop.dll
__Interop::ComCallHelpers Call() SharedStubs.g.cs:11991
UWP.McgInterop.dll
__Interop::ForwardComStubs.Stub_16_System __Canon_() SharedStubs.g.cs:645
UWP.exe
MyApp::App UnhandledError$catch$0() App.xaml.cs:34
System.ObjectModel.dll
System::ComponentModel::PropertyChangingEventHandler InvokeOpenStaticThunk() +0x0000000000000027
System.ObjectModel.dll
System::Collections::Specialized::NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler Invoke() +0x000000000000001B
UWP.McgInterop.dll
__Interop::Intrinsics.HasThisCall__45_System __Canon_() +0x0000000000000036
UWP.McgInterop.dll
__Interop::ReverseComStubs.Stub_9_System __Canon_() SharedStubs.g.cs:27913
```

I'd appreciate any help on how I might better implement extended execution to prevent this crash.

Answer (score -1):

For implementing the extended execution, I suggest you to follow the document [Postpone app suspension with extended execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution) and refer the official [ExtendedExecution](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ExtendedExecution) code sample, then check the code in your project to find where the issue happens.

Comment: telling me to look at the docs and check my code isn't an answer. Although a reference to the docs can be a useful part of an answer, it doesn't answer the question. My code above appears to be functionally equivalent to the docs. I've been unable to force an ExtendedExecution error on my dev machine, but this error is top of the pops for us in the Microsoft App Center, and the stack trace means little to me.

Comment: Your above code can not find any question where the issue happens so I can just provide the basic document for you to troubleshoot your project by yourself. Can you reproduce the crash in your device or provide a simple repro sample?Moreover you can try to use the Hockey app to collect the crash info to get more crash details [Crash Reporting for UWP](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/crash-reporting-for-uwp).

Comment: My understanding @Breeze Liu - MSFT is that HockeyApp has been integrated into Microsoft App Center. We have implemented App Center Analytics and App Center Crashes in our app. The stack trace above comes from a Microsoft App Center Crash report for our app.